# Security Clearance issue for work visa in Germany

Tags: germany, working-visas

I got an employment contract and an appointment at the German embassy. I went with all of the necessary documents and the embassy officer seemed satisfied with everything.

After a day, I received a call from the German consulate to show up in the embassy. I was not given any context of the invitation. So I came on time and then there was a kind of interview in which the officer told me that one of the agencies has raised **some security objection** to your visa application. He asked me whether I have visited Germany before or had any other business with German companies of some sort. I said no and it was the truth.

So I have never had any criminal record whatsoever in my country(not even a parking ticket). The officer said he does not know the details so he will call the Berlin office for more information and inform me later.

What can I do about this?

Comment: I doubt this question is answerable until you get the details from the officer. Meanwhile you could consider making an appointment to see an immigration lawyer

Comment: Have you ever had any problems in other Schengen countries? Otherwise you will just have to wait until you are informed about the details.

Comment: @Mark No issues with any one. I have never travelled outside my country. This is the first time.

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/57579/schengen-visa-refusal-on-threat-to-public-policy-security-health

Comment: Thanks traveller, i will list more details in the question as i get from the embassy. This is strange. I have never traveled anywhere (not outside my city) whole my life. Yet i have these accusations to deal with. I have an appointment with a legal practitioner for advise.

Answer (score 2):

Every so often we get questions like this from people with names that seem Arabic or Turkish or Muslim (for example, named after some prominent figure in the history of Islam).  Frequently, these names are obviously common.  My suspicion is that their names are similar to names on some watch list or another.  Whether this or some other reason is the cause of the "security objection," there is little you can do now but wait.

If they reject your application outright, you'll want to find out how to determine the reason and challenge the rejection.  If they grant the visa, you won't want to take any more action.  If they ask you for more information, you'll want to provide it, especially considering how to make yourself seem credible from their point of view (in other words, don't try to hide anything).

With any luck, they'll clear you on their own.  If not, come back and post a new question.

Comment: Yes my id card is in urdu which is very similar to arabic language. I have never hidden anything from them, i genuinely have no idea what is this all about.